# What differences are there between "to enhance" and "to improve"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, differences

What is the difference between the verbal synonyms "**to enhance**" and "**to improve**"? Do they have exactly the same meaning?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: What research have you already done?

Comment: @Luke: I looked on http://english.stackexchange.com, but nobody had asked that question yet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using *[enhance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enhance)* to mean *improve* in general and, at the same time, to mean *increase*, is a serious annoyance to people who care about the words they choose to use. M-W online says it means "heighten, increase; *especially* : to increase or improve in value, quality, desirability, or attractiveness". Academic writers in all fields, however, have jumped on this buzzword and use it to mean so many things that it has no meaning at all now. It's an academic isomorph of *nice*.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enhance) has a good example sentence of how to correctly use *enhance*: 
"to raise to a higher degree; intensify; magnify: *The candlelight enhanced her beauty*". She's already beautiful, but in the candlelight, she looks even more beautiful. It doesn't improve or increase her beauty: in the sunlight or the lamplight or the floodlight, she's not more beautiful because she stood in candlelight for a long time. The candlelight didn't actually increase or improve her beauty: if she was a 9 before the candlelight, she'll be a 9 after the candlelight. It merely made her **look like** a 10 while she was illuminated by candlelight.

Like all synonyms, sometimes they're interchangeable, but sometimes they're not. I've begun to hate the word *enhance*, so I almost always change it unless it's properly used in context.

Comment: I'd prefer to restrict the linguistic-domain usage of **isomorphic** to 'surface-structurally (though not necessarily syntactically) identical' {eg took the dog a bone; took the dog a walk}, not '(dis-?)functionally similar'!

Comment: @Edwin: Fair enough. "X was nice" and "X was enhanced". Okay, so the ADJs are different types and the similarities are dysfunctionally similar to be sure. Can you think of a better word for the similarity? I couldn't and still can't.

Comment: So "enhance" means improve existing features, so to say?

Comment: @Bill: _Analogue_ works - but it's so general in meaning (most general sense for analogy: 'agreement or similarity, esp in a certain limited number of features or details' - Collins) that one could say _analogue_ is an analogue of _nice_ too. _Correlate_ is a little less general. I suppose we could call the poor overworked words themselves instances of _overgeneralisations_ ( http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/broadenterm.htm ). Or perhaps _eleventy-ones_ - 'Sort of stretched, like butter scraped over too much bread'.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. It's true, the word is used terribly. I can't count the number of times I see it used incorrectly in (usually) commercial jargon. 

"Our product offers enhanced features"

"We need to do something to enhance sales!"

Answer (score 8):

To *improve* is to alter for the better, you remove what is not wanted and add what will make it better.

To *enhance* is simply to add a feature, you are not removing anything but adding something to make it stand out.

Answer (score 6):

They're close in meaning but enhanced implies some existing property or ability has been extended in some way or intensified whereas something could be improved in more general ways.

Answer (score 5):

In the audit field, we use the term "enhance" when something is in place and generally adequate but it needs a little more to be even better. For example, policies and procedures were in place to manage the risk of rogue trading but it did not say whether it is subject to periodic review and by whom.

We use "improve" when the shortcomings or weaknesses are material and render something inadequate or not up to expectations. Using the same example, the policies and procedures needs improvement because it did not spell out the mechanism to monitor and control trades by traders outside trading hours and off-premise.

To auditors, there is a clear distinction between the two terms.

Comment: Can you present any evidence whether this distinction holds generally?

Answer (score 3):

*To enhance* is to add something (More functionality, more ability, more option).

*To improve* is to make the something better - no additions, just improvement of what was already there.